# My app works perfectly locally, all routes, with no issues. But on Heroku, all employees routes are getting a 503 service unavailable

Tags: node.js, reactjs, heroku, passport.js

I'm using passport authentication on a local database for two kind of users, admin and employees. The whole app works well locally but on Heroku, employees cannot be signed up or signed in. It's giving me a 503 unavailable service error. Any clue?

I have tried postman and I'm getting the same reponse after 30+ seconds.

```
 // Register
router.post('/employees/signup', (req, res) => {
console.log(req.body);

const { firstName, lastName, email, password, password2, jobType } = 
req.body;

if (password.length < 6) {
    throw 'Password must be at least 6 characters';
}
else {
    Employee.findOne({
        where: {
            email
        }
    }).then(employee => {
        if (employee) {
            res.send("Email already exists!")
        } else {
            const encryptedPassword = bcrypt.hashSync(password, salt);

            let newEmployee = {
                firstName,
                lastName,
                email,
                password: encryptedPassword,
                jobType,
            };
            Employee.create(newEmployee)
                .then(() => {
                    delete newEmployee.password;
                    res.send(newEmployee)
                })
                .catch(function (err) {
                    console.log(err);
                    res.json(err);
                });
            }
        });
    }

});

// Login
    router.post("/employees/login", function (req, res, next) {
        const { email, password } = req.body;
        // generate the authenticate method and pass the req/res
        passport.authenticate('employees-local', function (err, employee, 
   info) {
        if (!email || !password) {
            return
        }
        if (err) {
            return res.status(401).json(err);
        }
        if (!employee) {
            return res.status(401).json(info);
        }

    // req / res held in closure
    req.logIn(employee, () => {
        Employee.findOne({
            where: {
                email: req.body.email,
            },
        }).then(employee => {
            const token = jwt.sign({ email: employee.email }, 
jwtSecret.secret, {
                expiresIn: 60 * 60,
            });
            res.status(200).send({
                authEmployee: true,
                token,
                message: 'user found & logged in',
                employee
             });
          });
      });

    })(req, res, next);

});


//Getting all employees
router.get("/employees", (req, res) => {
    Employee.findAll({}).then(function (dbEmployee) {
        res.json(dbEmployee);
    });
});
```

Comment: Are you 100% sure your database is configured properly and working on Heroku?

Comment: Also, what's with `throw 'Password must be at least 6 characters';` in your route handler.  There's none of your code to catch that.

Comment: Also, your login route has all sorts of paths through it that you send no response. Every path through that must send some sort of response back to the client.

Comment: If you put a `console.log("I'm here")` in your route, does that show in the console?

Comment: On JAWS_DB I have clients admins "employees" and 3 calendar tables so I'm assuming it's properly configured since only the employees routes are not getting proper responses.Thanks for pointing out those lines on the code, but I don't see how they affect the calls to the routes(the throw 'Password.)I agree it doesn't do anything). Also about that last comment: I'm sending all those kind of responses to the client to validate the request. I get them on the front end for validation as messages. And lastly I send the JWT token and some more data. About the 503 is there anything I could do?

Comment: Debug where the 503 is coming from.  You need to know which line of code is causing/sending it.

Comment: I used breakpoints and it's showing me the error comes from the front end where I'm using axios.post(), so I'll try to modify some things if that works

Comment: 503 should be a server error, not something axios manufactures in the front-end.

Comment: @jfriend00 The problem came when some time ago I wanted to create a personal profile for the employees, so I had created a model for the employees profile. Then I had changed my mind but never deleted that model; so Sequelize kept trying to associate employees with the profiles model, therefore, the routes were not getting hit. It's been solved now by just deleting that old model, and I'm not getting that 503 anymore. Thanks a lot for your input as it helped me think from a different perspective and reach out to the problem the correct way and correct unnecessary lines of code.

Answer (score 0):

The problem came when some time ago I wanted to create a personal profile for the employees, so I had created a model for the employees profile. Then I had changed my mind but never deleted that model; so Sequelize kept trying to associate employees with the profiles model, therefore, the routes were not getting hit. It's been solved now by just deleting that old model, and I'm not getting that 503 anymore. Thanks a lot for your input as it helped me think from a different perspective and reach out to the problem the correct way and correct unnecessary lines of code.